Symfony Doctrine have two property for the same column in database
Here's a sample entity
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ORM\Table(name: 'user')]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [new GetCollection()],
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => [
            'user:id',
            'user:score',
            'user:user_score',
        ],
    ]
)]
class User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'ID_USER', type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(groups: ['user:id'])]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'SCORE', type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(groups: ['user:score'])]
    private int $score;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'SCORE', type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(groups: ['user:user_score'])]
    private int $userScore;

    // getters / setters
}

I want to deprecate $score / user:score and remove it from the API endpoint
But can't do this in 1 step, I need to do first 2 field with the same value in it and second remove the unwanted field
How to do that?

Is this the same as $userScore?  Why can't you do this in one step?

I need to support the legacy for a while before I can completely remove the old field.
the frontend needs this field.

If the frontend needs this field, what  exactly should be done in the first step if removing is not an option? What would "2 field with the same value in it" mean, and why isn't this working already?

Idealy your API exposed the getters and setters,
probably the serializer uses them anyway
so to deprecate you could modify your getter and setter like:
/**
 * @deprecated in 2.x and removed in 3.x.
 *   Use \Foo\Bar::getUserScore() instead.
 */
public function getScore(){
  return $this->getUserScore();
}

so any calls to getScore will return the userScore property anyway. You can then remove it in some version.

I solved the problem with the SerializedName annotation
Thanks

Solved code
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ORM\Table(name: 'user')]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [new GetCollection()],
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => [
            'user:id',
            'user:score',
            'user:user_score',
        ],
    ]
)]
class User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'ID_USER', type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(groups: ['user:id'])]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'SCORE', type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(groups: ['user:user_score'])]
    private int $userScore;

    #[Groups(groups: ['user:score'])]
    #[SerializedName('score')]
    public function getScore()
    {
        return $this->userScore;
    }

    // getters / setters
}

